# Loading /Inserting Multiple XML files into Oracle table at once

Tags: oracle12c, xmltable

I have a table xml_table_date. Below is the structure and sample data in the table.

But I want to insert multiple xml files (here it is 9) into the table in one go. These files resides in a DB directory

My code to insert xml file into the table:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_table_data (
  File_name  varchar2(100),
  Insert_date timestamp
  xml_data  XMLTYPE
);

INSERT INTO xml_tab VALUES ( 'DataTransfer_HH_TWWholesale_001_004_12142020113003.xml', 
                              XMLTYPE (BFILENAME ('TESTING', 'DataTransfer_HH_TWWholesale_001_004_12142020113003.xml'),NLS_CHARSET_ID ('AL32UTF8')));
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me on this.. Thanks for reading my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external table with preproxessing to read the filenames from the directory.

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=pdb1;

CREATE DIRECTORY data_dir   AS '/u02/data';
CREATE DIRECTORY script_dir AS '/u02/scripts';
CREATE DIRECTORY log_dir    AS '/u02/logs';

GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY   data_dir   TO demo1;
GRANT READ, EXECUTE ON DIRECTORY script_dir TO demo1;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY   log_dir    TO demo1;
```

Create a list_files.sh file in the scripts-directory. Make sure oracle is the owner and the privileges are 755 on the file.
The preprocessing script file don't inherit the $PATH enviroment variable. So you have to prepend /usr/bin before all commands.

```
/usr/bin/ls -1 /u02/data/test*.xml | /usr/bin/xargs -n1 /usr/bin/basename
```

You also need a source file for the external table, but this can be an empty dummy file.

```
CREATE TABLE data_files
   ( file_name VARCHAR2(255))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
   TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_dir
   ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
        PREPROCESSOR script_dir: 'list_files.sh'
        BADFILE log_dir:'list_files_%a_%p.bad'
        LOGFILE log_dir:'list_files_%a_%p.log'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE
      )
   LOCATION ('dummy.txt')
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Now you can insert the xml data into your table.

```
INSERT INTO xml_table_data
   ( file_name,
     insert_date,
     xml_data
   )
SELECT file_name,
       SYSTIMESTAMP,
       XMLTYPE (BFILENAME ('DATA_DIR', file_name), NLS_CHARSET_ID ('AL32UTF8'))
  FROM data_files;
```

You still need to adapt the example to your environment, please.